# Stretching a nested table in a cell

Tags: html, css, html-table

The following a snapshot of http://jsfiddle.net/mark69_fnd/LftRY/ on Chrome:

[image]

Notice, that the inner tables intended for addresses are not properly stretched - they are one or two pixels short on their right side. This is despite the 100% width that is given to the table element in the css and no padding/margin.

How can I make these tables occupy the complete space of the enclosing cell?

**EDIT**

All of the browsers exhibit some kind of a problem. My code does not show proper stretching in neither of Chrome, IE9, Firefox.

**EDIT2**

Firefox - the same problem, but on the left side:

[image]

IE9 - the same problem, but on the right side of "Bill To" and on the left side of "Ship To":

[image]

**EDIT3**

I have resorted to tables, because I just could not make it work with `<div>` and have all the elements properly aligned and stretched. If anyone posts a reply which solves all the described problems and behaves the same as the table based solution - I will happily credit and adopt it.

Comment: Nested tables! AH MY EYES!! It **b̢̛ͥͣͯͪ̔͛̀̚ú̾̀͡rͦ̑ͩ̎͑͑̅̏͢ñ̴͋̆҉̛s͆͆ͪͩ͒́ͣ͡**!

Comment: @Truth - if you provide a reply with an equivalent jsFiddle without the tables solving my problem and with exactly the same behavior with respect to resizing, alignment, etc... - I will credit your reply as the answer.

Comment: It is simply the border space of the `td` element. Rethinking your borders a bit will help you solve the problem. Put the border on the `td`s, not the inner `table`s.

Comment: @mark: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do here, what is the application purpose, and what are the requirements from it? (i.e. does it have to look exactly like that?)

Comment: In firefox it looks fine, but in chrome it looks as OP said..

Comment: @Truth - I will settle for a jsFiddle doing exactly the same as mine.

Comment: @A.K. - it does not look fine on Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a big fan of using tables, though in this case a table is by far the best solution. It is after all tabular data you are going to display.

That beeing said, I don't think you should work with nested tables here, it just complicates things imo. Just keep working with the colspans as you where, and you can easily achieve the same result. Also it will eliminate the problems with the borders you are experiencing now. Have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/LftRY/21/

Note that is also made some changes to the `input` css. I removed all borders, paddings and margins, so i could set them to 100% width to force them to take the same width as their parent. Also i removed the `<br>` tags in your html, and set the inputs to display as block elements. I am not a big fan of using the `<br>` unless absolutly required (wich is rarely the case).

I also added a class, `.no-lines`, wich you can use on cells or rows you want to display without borders. As you can see I used them on the 'gap' between the two addresses in the header, as well as on the footer i added as an example. You could even use it on entire rows if you want.

Further i took the liberty to add `thead`, `tbody` and `tfoot` tags to the table html. This will improve access for people with screenreaders, be much better for SEO, and is just semanticly more correct imo.

Hope this is what you where after. If not, feel free to ask!

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much. This is exactly what I was looking for. One question, though. What was my mistake?

Comment: cause you where using nested tables, the border of the cell the nested table was in was lying against teh border of the nested table, wich made it look twice a wide. Border collapse does not prevent this on nested tables.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make these tables occupy the complete space of the enclosing cell?

You already did. However what you constitute with your mind what the "complete space of the enclosing cell" would be, is technically wrong in the browser you moan about.

It's 100% width, fully filled up. As @bažmegakapa commented above you should re-think how you draw the borders, e.g. you might just want to not collapse them, prefer inner above outer borders (or the opposite but more strict than now) to easier cross-browser style the borders.

Or otherwise, dig into the details and learn - even with trial and error - how to collapse borders to your needs.

http://jsfiddle.net/LftRY/3/

[image]

Comment: I am learning and digging. And posting to this site is part of the learning. I am sorry, does your jsFiddle show how to solve the problem?

Comment: You should probably learn what collapse means: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#propdef-border-collapse - you can use first, but if you run into a problem, then try to read about what you actually did next - do not just think you did everything right just in the first place.